# Getting django model errors for a model I am trying to delete

Tags: django

Can you help?

I made a mistake on my Django models.py and wanted to then delete the model.

As you can see from the below, the migration was to delete the model called code.

However, it still errors & doesn't delete the model.

What can I do?

```
root@new:/home/django/django_project# python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'netshock':
  netshock/migrations/0018_delete_code.py
    - Delete model code
root@new:/home/django/django_project# python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, netshock, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying netshock.0012_code...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 129, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 97, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 303, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 120, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "4000000000"
LINE 1: ...("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "code" varchar(4000000000...
```

Comment: The error clearly says that the `4000000000` near `varchar(4000000000)` is wrong. One of the fields you defined simply is way too large.

Comment: Yeah - I tried to change the field size, but it wouldn't. So I have removed the model from models.py. All I want it to do is delete the model, but its still moaing about it

Comment: that is (very) likely because that specific migration file is still there. So you can not "get passed" that migration. You should review what migrations you can throw away and make new ones.

Comment: You've just become my favourite person in the whole world :) - can you add deleting the files as an answer and I'll mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is specified at the bottom of the error:

> ```
> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "4000000000"
> LINE 1: ...("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "code" varchar(4000000000...
> ```

Now `4000000000` is simply too large. PostgreSQL mentions that the [maximum size of character types is 1GB [PostgreSQL-doc]](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/datatype-character.html):

> (...) In any case, the **longest possible character string** that can
>   be stored is about **1 GB**. (The **maximum value that will be allowed
>   for *n* in the data type declaration is less** than that. It wouldn't
>   be useful to change this because with multibyte character encodings
>   the number of characters and bytes can be quite different. If you
>   desire to store long strings with no specific upper limit, use text or
>   character varying without a length specifier, rather than making up an
>   arbitrary length limit.)

So setting this to 4'000'000'000 makes no sense.

If you later make extra changes, this will not resolve the issue (at least not immediately), since you created migration files with the `4000000000` in these. You will have to remove the migration files that can not be applied (together with the ones that follow on these migrations, since otherwise there is *likely* an error in the *chain*), and make new migration files.